# Is there a way to group a dataframe by certain elements of its content without a given delimiter?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I'm facing the following situation. I have a dataframe which looks like this (due to sensitivity of the data I have to paraphrase it)

```
Column A     Column B
A1B12C123    Japan
A2B34C456    Switzerland
A3B45C789    Japan
A1B15C729    Japan
```

My goal is to group Column A by the recurring pattern, which describes a certain property.
Meaning: Group by A1, Group by B12, Group by C123.

In order to do that, I split the Column and created new ones for each level of hierarchy, e.g.:

```
  Column A     Column B  Column C
    A1           B12      C123
    A2           B34      C456
    A3           B45      C789
    A1           B15      C729
```

Those columns I have to add to my existing dataframe, and then I'll be able to group the way I wanted to.
I think this can work, but it seems a bit tedious and unelegant.

Is there a possibility or a way in Pandas to do this more elegantly?
I'd be happy about any input on that matter.

Best regards

Comment: You have done a good job

Comment: You may use Regex Patterns to extract portions of the initial Column A and place the extract in a new column

Comment: kindly add your expected output

Answer (score 1):

Taking Seyi Daniel's idea from the comments, you can use `exctractall()` string [method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html#pandas.Series.str.extractall) on the Column A to explode it based on regex groups and join Column B on to it.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""
Column_A     Column_B
A1B12C123    Japan
A2B34C456    Switzerland
A3B45C789    Japan
A1B15C729    Japan
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)

regex_df = df["Column_A"].str.extractall(r"(A\d*)|(B\d*)|(C\d*)")

# drop extra levels
regex_s = regex_df.stack().reset_index((1,2), drop=True)
# give the new column a name
regex_s.name = "group"
# add column B
result = pd.merge(regex_s, df["Column_B"], left_index=True, right_index=True)

print(result)

  group     Column_B
0    A1        Japan
0   B12        Japan
0  C123        Japan
1    A2  Switzerland
1   B34  Switzerland
1  C456  Switzerland
2    A3        Japan
2   B45        Japan
2  C789        Japan
3    A1        Japan
3   B15        Japan
3  C729        Japan
```